# composer install * file_put_contents * failed to open stream

Tags: php, composer-php, bitbucket

I have a Drupal project on the Bit-bucket Repository.

So there is a piplines.yml in the directory and showed bellow

```
# This is a sample build configuration for PHP.
# Check our guides at https://confluence.atlassian.com/x/e8YWN for more examples.
# Only use spaces to indent your .yml configuration.
# -----
# You can specify a custom docker image from Docker Hub as your build environment.
image: php:7.3.10

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - composer
        script:
          - apt-get update && apt-get install -y unzip libfreetype6-dev libjpeg62-turbo-dev git
          - docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg-dir=/usr/include/
          - docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd
          - curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
          - cd docroot
          - composer install
          - vendor/bin/phpcs --config-set installed_paths vendor/drupal/coder/coder_sniffer
          - vendor/bin/phpcs -i
          - vendor/bin/phpcs --standard=Drupal --extensions=php,module,inc,install,test,profile,theme,css,info,txt,md --ignore=node_modules,bower_components,vendor modules/custom
          - vendor/bin/phpcs --standard=DrupalPractice --extensions=php,module,inc,install,test,profile,theme,css,info,txt,md --ignore=node_modules,bower_components,vendor modules/custom
```

The issue comes up on composer install section, that shows this error 
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to https://github.com/Chi-teck/drupal-code-generator
dcg your error refers to is an executable you need to have in your project FIRST
please make sure to install it in your docroot before you run install, or make sure it is part of your dependencies of composer.json and composer.lock

EDIT: after deeper investigation it turned out the dcg was tracked within docroot/vendor dir (because it was not gitignored) and commited as a link to cygwin dcg.bat file. This couldn't work on php7.3 docker image and that's caused all the trouble.

removing tracked vendor folder and adding `docroot/vendor` to gitignore solved the issue.

Comment: I installed it but still the same error happens. ```$ composer require chi-teck/drupal-code-generator
Using version ^1.31 for chi-teck/drupal-code-generator
```

Comment: 1. can you share your composer.json ? 2.did you make sure run a NEW build after you have comitted composer.json and composer.lock?

Comment: I put my composer.json file here, please check. https://api.myjson.com/bins/fr084

Comment: what do you mean by `run a NEW build `?

Comment: considering the path in your screenshot you are running bitbucket pipelines. as far as I remember those are triggered every deploy (unless you set otherwise) so that build screenshot refers to specific SHA in repository. Can you make sure your build contains the DGC?
since your composer says there's nothing to install, can you add this: ls -al vendor/bin and see what things are listed there?

Comment: this is not what we're looking for. your pipeline runs within docker image that's not cygwin. please modify your pipeline and check the ls-al in there. it should show you something like this:
https://pastebin.com/jL3Ug3p3

Comment: I think it shows the content of the file as well. here is the cleaned result for dcg > ```lrwxrwxrwx.  1 root root  369 Dec 11 08:03 dcg -> #!/usr/bin/env sh
-rw-rw-rw-.  1 root root  128 Dec 11 08:03 dcg.bat```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204034/discussion-between-janmyszkier-and-nasser-ali-karimi).

Comment: ok, so the problem here seems to be you're tracking vendor folder